# KDE: Immediat visual feedback when switching window

Tags: kde, desktop-customization, kde-plasma-workspace

I have been searching through the many different KDE settings to achieve a particular behavior when switching window with key shortcut, but cannot find it : I want that when cycling through windows, the selected window get the focus immediatly before I release the modifier key of the shortcut.

For instance:

- I press the Alt key and keep it down
- I press the Tab key and release it
- At this point, several things can occur depending on my KDE setting:

  - I can have one of the *windows cycling popup* showing me the next window selected, or nothing  (Window Behavior/Task Switcher).
  - I can have the selected window raised above the other (same tab)
  - I can have all the non selected windows becoming transparent (Desktop Effect/Highlight Window, despites what this effect pretends to do)
- I can press Tab again, and have the same effects above occurring on the next selected window
- Then I release the Alt key
- The last selected window get the focus and its titlebar is highlighted (e.g. turns from light grey to vivid blue)

What I would like here is that the last event occurs before I release the Alt key (or any other visual feedback occurring immediately on the selected window). In some screen/window configurations, I do not have this feedback and this is quite disturbing to select a window and do not see anything happening to it.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with KDE 4.13.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but as far as I can tell you cannot have it and the feedback working at the same time.  To do this, go to `system settings` (or `configure desktop`) -> '`Shortcuts and Gestures` -> `Global keyboard shortcuts` -> `kwin` -> `lower window` and set its shortcut to `Alt+Tab` (or some alternative if you prefer).

This will do what you want, but it is kind of hacky, since it isn't exactly the same thing as walking through windows (although for most cases it should behave pretty much the same).

Comment: Hacky, but exactly what I needed ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want is exactly what https://github.com/ohjames/kwin-window-switch does. It works with Plasma 5.